# why I cant use border radius and border collapse simentaniously

Tags: html, css, border

I was working with my HTML project I am unable to use both border collapse and border radius at same time
can I use both of them together by using any special method...?

Comment: With what CSS and HTML; where's your relevant "*[mcve]*" code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-spacing :0 instead of border-collapse: collapse

I'm not sure this is what you want but this will be helpful.